# Simplifying Javascript if statement undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, typeof

```
if (typeof $scope.input.gps === 'undefined') {
    $scope.msgBody  = 'Location not found.';
} else {
    $scope.msgBody  = $scope.input.gps+' not found.';
}
flash.pop({title: 'Error', body: $scope.msgBody, type: 'error'});
```

Would there be an easier way to do this if statement and include it inside the `flash.pop`

Comment: Why? What is your definition of "easier"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with clear, easily maintained code even if it's a few characters more to type initially, it might save a lot of time and effort later.

Seems you need to set the value of $scope.msgBody, I don't think it's a good idea to do that in the assignment. Consider:

```
$scope.msgBody = typeof $scope.input.gps === 'undefined'? 'Location not found.' :
                                                          $scope.input.gps + ' not found.'
```

However, I don't think that's "easier".

Answer (score 3):

You may use `$scope.msgBody = ($scope.input.gps || 'Location') + ' not found.';`.

But note that `Location` will be used not only if `$scope.input.gps` is `undefined`, but also if `null`, `""`, `0`, `NaN` and `false`. Those values are covered by the `falsy` concept, see http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/.